# cannot run my html and tailwind css code on my mobile

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, tailwind-css

I write a sample website code in vscode using  html and tailwind css it execute properly when i run on my laptop using "npm run start" command and after buliding using "npm run build" command it create dist folder that conatian html file , "index.6a7c7d54.css" and assests folder that have my images that i used there in my code. I run that code using live server it also run properly

But when i copy my entire folder to my mobile phone and tried to run that html file it only show html output not css output.

if anyone has any idea please share your thoughts Thank you

Comment: How do you copy it to your phone? You can just run it on your pc localhost and then use your oc’s IP address to view the site on your phone!

Comment: can you explain please @kokodoko

Comment: To watch your site on your phone you need some kind of server. How do you test currently?

Comment: I am using vscode with terminal command npm run start . In web it show as "localhost 3000"

Comment: Let me explain....  @Kokodoko        I write a sample code of html and tailwind css  in vs code for a simple paractice website. I run my code using "npm run start " command it works properly in my browser. Than i want to test my code to check weather its is responsive and working properly in my phone. So i copy my html file along with other associated files to my phone and try to open html code. but it only show the output of html not for the properties of css that i include using tailwind css.

Comment: But you still haven't explained what you mean by "I copy my html file to my phone". In any case, I would suggest running a server and opening that server url on your phone. For example, by putting your test files online, or by getting your localhost IP address and opening that on your phone.